# How to add special symbols to custom PyCharm TODO comments?

Tags: pycharm, comments

I want to add a new TODO comment in PyCharm so that if I type out `# ! [comment]`,
the comment will be highlighted in red (Kinda like what they have in the Better Comments plugin).

However, when I tried adding a new TODO pattern, it did not work. It works when I use words in the pattern, but it appears that PyCharm not allow special characters like `!`, `@` etc.

[This is what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lKpW.png)

`\b!\b*` does not work rest all do

Comment: This has to do with the 3rd party plugin you're using, not with PyCharm itself. Given that that plugin hasn't been updated in years, and that its most recent reviews are all variations of "doesn't work", I think it's safe to say that this is an issue with the plugin.

Comment: There are other actively maintained comment-highligher plugins you can try. However, plugin recommendation questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brian61354270 I am talking about the built-in comment feature in PyCharm where you can make your own comments/edit them, i am just trying to copy Better Comment

Comment: From your edit it I see you're talking about TODOs. I edited your question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Brian61354270 ty, still new to stack overflow so still learning 